# PowerShell 5.1 Set-Acl

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I try to use Set-Acl in my PowerShell script if just I make

`$my_acl = Get-Acl "C:\" 
Set-Acl D:\ $my_acl`

This work in Admin

but if I try to launch script in User en elevate to Admin

`$my_acl = Get-Acl "C:\" 
$arg5={param($my_acl,)(Set-Acl D:\ $my_acl )}
Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-noexit -command & {$arg5} $my_acl" -Verb RunAs`

I got this error

`Set-Acl : AclObject
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 19
+ & {param($my_acl)(Set-Acl D:\ $my_acl )} System.Security.AccessContro ...
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument : (System.Security...rectorySecurity:String) [Set-Acl], ArgumentExceptio
   n
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetAcl_AclObject,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAclCommand`

EDIT:

Thank for the solution PRASOON KARUNAN V the solution is really nice, but I just make:

`Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "Get-Acl C:\ | Set-Acl D:\" -Credential ($credentials_admin)
Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "Get-Acl C:\Users\$($my_user) | Set-Acl D:\$($my_user)" -Credential ($credentials_admin)`

I just pipe out the result of Get-Acl in my Set-Acl and it's ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script have problems.

- You don't need to set the scrtipblock to a variable, better to call
  it directly.
- There was a unwanted comma in param block.
- Parenthesis are not required here `(Set-Acl D:\ $my_acl )`

```
$my_acl = Get-Acl "C:\" 
Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-noexit -command & {param(`$my_acl) Set-Acl D:\ `$my_acl} $my_acl" -Verb RunAs
```

Like below, we have to escape the `$` sign so that the value no not invoked when those are using in double quotes.

```
`$My_acl
```